# При ресайзе страницы медиа запросы срабатывают позже

Tags: css

К примеру на 920px страница должна переходить в раблетную версию, но она срабатывает на 903px?!
Размер браузера стоит 100%
прописан вьюпорт

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Запрос должен срабатывать на 920px а не на 903px

Во всех медиа запросах произошло смещение на 17px. А вот если открывать с моб версии - тогда все работает корректно

Comment: Ширина полосы прокрутки обычно 17px, так что 903px **внутренней** части плюс 17px прокрутки = 920px вьюпорта

Comment: Но было ведь все нормально ? Или хром начал учитывать этот момент в полосу?